# search for php with str_replace - dont want code rendered

Tags: php, str-replace

Can anyone help me out?
Im trying to replace some code on a bunch of websites at once, and I have done this before..
Problem here is, the code I need to replace is PHP, and when I look for it with str_replace, it wants to render the php code, insteed of looking for the charecter match as I want it to do:

```
$file_contents = str_replace("info@<? echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>","info@mydomain.com",$file_contents);
```

The problem is, it tries to render that php, instead of looking for those characters..
Is there anything one can do in this situation?

Comment: This is not a PHP issue, this is a file search and replace issue.

Comment: The code being used to do the replace is PHP, and the problem appears to be PHP's interpolation of strings.

Comment: Ah I see, let's just say I'm not a fan of this approach.

Comment: why not open all the files in notepad++ (it'll handle a few thousand files at once) just do a search and replace all it'll take it 2 seconds.

Comment: that would entail downloading the files, then  uploading, there are hundreds of sites in two servers, and Jessicas answer solved it, I just changed 200+ incorrect phone number across 200+ websites in seconds..

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes instead of double, and then `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will be interpreted as a literal string instead of a variable. You'll need to escape the single quotes within the string.

```
 $file_contents = str_replace('info@<? echo $_SERVER[\'SERVER_NAME\']; ?>',"info@mydomain.com",$file_contents);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and I understand why now.. Thank you!